# iOS Plist Object Count Error?

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, plist

I am initializing several .plist files with 256 objects into a `NSMutableArray` with the following code:

```
NSMutableArray *return_list = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:list_name ofType:@".plist"]];

NSLog(@"numitems: %d", [return_list count]);
```

Out of 10 plists, this code is correctly loading and counting the number of items in the list. However, for one of the plists, it is consistently listing the item count as 253, which is very perplexing.

Plist edit pro says "256 ordered objects", and the built-in Xcode plist viewer claims the same number.

What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible there's a nesting error in your property list file?  There might be 256 objects in the file, but only 253 that are top-level objects, with the other three inadvertently being children of one of the others.

If that's not it, I would suspect a formatting error in the plist.  Open it as code and take a look at the raw XML.